# Hosting multiple sites on a single IIS installation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been working on several small ASP.Net MVC websites running on .Net 4.5 and IIS 8 for some time now and want to deploy them on production server. I have some questions that I need to be answered before I go on to do it well. I tried searching but nowhere I got satisfactory answers. Note that I only have a single web server (on AWS EC2), which I am making use of for all my sites. So, please let me know about these queries -

a) Is it feasible to run multiple sites on one single App Pool or should I create different App Pool for each site? Does the working of one site effect how other sites run in the same App Pool?

b) How many App Pools (Integrated/Classic) can be created in a single installation of IIS?

c) Can we set some kind of limits to the resources (CPU/Memory/Storage) that each App Pool/Website can use at maximum?

d) If I want to run each site on separate domains/sub-domains, will I be able to do it for each of them simultaneoulsy? Do I need to open more ports on the machine or will only changing the host name mapping and keep port 80 do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) yes, it's possible but it will run under the same RAM and CPU limits. Also, if one app pool crashes all the sites under that apppool will crash and will be restarted.

b) I don't know, but if you have enough RAM I think it's better to have each site on each app pool.

c) Yes for RAM and CPU. In IIS8 the CPU limits feature was improved. For storage limit maybe you should use Windows users disk quotas (not related with IIS but to Windows Server).

d) Yes, sure. You should use host-headers binding on each site to have all running under port 80.